# Root CA using SHA1withRSA and individual certificate with SHA384withRSA

Tags: java, cryptography

My individual certificate signed with SHA256withRSA works fine with our application. It however fails to work with individual key signed with SHA384withRSA signature algorithms.

My root CA is signed with SHA1withRSA. Does this make any difference?
Do I need to update the ROOT CA also to SHA384withRSA or higher?

Comment: "Fails to work" is not a correct error description. What is wrong and what have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Hi Arpeet & welcome. Well, I replied quickly. That cannot be said of you however, please update your question if requested. Note that asking for a quick reply is often not taken well. This is not a payed service.

Answer (score 0):

No, the signature algorithm of the root CA should not make a difference. There are many certificates out there where the root CA and the children of the root CA have a different algorithm. Besides that, if it was a problem your previous certificate should have failed as well.

Note that SHA1 based certificates are being phased out by all the major players. So please make sure that any other party is still able to base trust on them. This however can be seen as a separate issue; the fact that the client has another algorithm has little to nothing to do with that.

It is of course free for any party to reject certificate chains if the security provided by the certificates is too dissimilar. But that practice is not standardized to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Maarteen for your quick response. No, I was wondering if it could be an issue with the root CA. Now, its clear after your reply that something is wrong with our application that just does not validate the certificate..Again thanks for the reply!!